# Laravel Livewire update model field

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a simple livewire component, I have a textarea field named description that when updated, will fill another input with a part of it.
I can update the description field with that part, but the name field not.

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Traits\ProcessTrait;

class RecordName extends Component
{
    use ProcessTrait;

    public $name;
    public $record;
    public $description;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.record-name');
    }

    public function updatedDescription()
    {
        $data = $this->getRecordData($this->description);
        $this->name = $data['filename'];
        $this->description = $data['filename'];
    }

}
```

And the view

```
<div class="mt-4">
    <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="description">{{ __('Description') }}</label>
    <textarea wire:model.lazy="description" 
    class="rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 block mt-1 w-full"
    id="description" name="description" cols="100"
    rows="4" >{{ old('description', is_null($record) ? '' : $record->description) }}</textarea>
</div>
<div class="mt-4">
    <label class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700" for="name">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
    <input wire:model="name" id="name" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name', is_null($record) ? '' : $record->name) }}" 
    class="rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 block mt-1 w-full"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I made it work by making another component for that field. Can't I have 2 wire:model in same component?

Comment: Of course you can. wire:model directive only bind the frontend element with backend property

Comment: @Prospero So why I can access only $this->description? $this->name is set but only available inside component, not updating the field at all.

Comment: do you know using wire:model.lazy it's only update the property on blur element right? and, why are you using "value" attribute? this may cause conflict with binding property?

Comment: @Prospero I'm using value because I use this for edit and create resource, and the old() does the job for everything

Comment: old() is a Laravel resource to, for example, form validations feedback...I really don't use it at all with Livewire

Comment: @Prospero So you think if I remove value attribute will work? If I do this I have to make different views for edit and create

Comment: In livewire we don't use old(), I think thats the problem. You can use the same component to edit and create, you don't need to add a different view.

Comment: @AlexandruPopa there is nothing wrong if you decide create separates components for it. There is an approach of reuse a same component for both, but I think you're not forced to this.

Comment: @Prospero Thing is I made it work with separate components, but I would really like to understand how to do it in the same component. I'm new to Livewire/Laravel and OOP, so all is a bit shady

Comment: Don't worry, I understand you...all of us have been there. But there is a lot of tutorials and videos that could help you to achieve it. I suggest you begin from there, and if any issue, come here! For me, this was the best video tutorial I found for start learning Livewire, enjoy it!. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSP81gW0XjNFP8RTBLMb1KL7Qbr8hUjr4